# Issues with merging two bitmaps

Tags: android, ios, actionscript-3, bitmap, cross-platform

I'm trying to add one bitmap (png file) on top of another and then save it to the device. Everything works fine except for the first part.

Bits of my code:

> 1 converting loaded file to bitmap

```
loadedBitmap = e.target.content as Bitmap;
clonedBitmap = new Bitmap(loadedBitmap.bitmapData.clone());

bitmapData = new BitmapData(e.target.content.width, e.target.content.height);
bitmapData.draw(clonedBitmap);
```

> 2 second Bitmap generated within the app

```
genBitmapData = new BitmapData(bgWidth, bgHeight, false);
genBitmap = new Bitmap(genBitmapData);
```

> 3 adding clonedBitmap (external file) to the bitmapdata

```
var positionMatrix : Matrix = new Matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0);
genBitmapData.draw(clonedBitmap, positionMatrix);
```

The problem with the step three is that the loaded file clonedBitmap end up being under the bitmap generated by the app upon saving it to the device's storage. When I reverse the order:

```
bitmapData.draw(genBitmap, positionMatrix);
```

Only the generated bitmap is displayed/visible while the loaded bitmap isn't visible at all upon saving the file. What I'd like to achieve is to have clonedBitmap (external png file) to be on top of the genBitmap and saved withing a BitmapData object, so I could be able to save it to my device.

I'd be grateful for any tips.

Comment: You do something really weird here. Can't you just work with two **Bitmap** objects and z-order them as you want? Also, cloning bitmap by **draw**inng when you can just clone the original **BitmapData** is another weird thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

When you draw a bitmap over a bitmap, you need the bitmap being overlayed to be transparent somewhere, otherwise all the lower bitmap's pixels would be overwritten with the upper layer. Therefore, create those bitmaps with alpha channel (transparency=true), make sure the upper layer bitmap is also transparent after you draw a something on it (at least somewhere), then draw first lower layer then upper layer on a *single* `BitmapData` object.

Note that since you don't transform any bitmaps, you'd better use `BitmapData.copyPixels()` method.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the code works fine. I just overlooked and placed it in the wrong function, which caused the issue.